# Aborting from inside a Dialog

Tags: programming

Suppose I got in a `Dialog` and wanted to not `Return` but `Abort` the computation. How could I do that?

Using `Return[]` the computation continues, and sometimes that implies getting inside countless other `Dialog`s of which it is not easy to go out without killing the kernel.

How do you handle those situations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use `ExitDialog@Unevaluated@Abort[]`

If your dialog is unhappily inside a `CheckAbort` you can go for exceptions like  `ExitDialog@Unevaluated@Throw["OOOUT", Unique[]]` for example.

In this way, tools like `TraceDialog` become very useful. `TraceDialog[code, Message]` is something I use often, to see the `Stack`, the state, etc

Note that this only aborts one level. If you want 2 levels you could do `ExitDialog@Unevaluated@ExitDialog@Unevaluated@Abort[]`

For a general way to abort all dialogs of any level at once, one could do

```
Apply[Composition,
  ConstantArray[Function[i, ExitDialog@Unevaluated@i, HoldFirst], 
   DialogLevel[]]][Unevaluated@Abort[]]
```

Comment: Seems that `ExitDialog` is equivalent to `Return` in this case?

Comment: @xzczd in what case?

Comment: I mean `ExitDialog@Unevaluated@Abort[]` and `Return@Unevaluated@Abort[]` has the same effect?

Comment: @xzczd That didn't work for me last I tried. It made the dialog return `Unevaluated@Abort[]` so nothing got aborted.

Comment: @xzczd yeah. It seems `Return` returns even  when run without `[...]`, and the `Unevaluated` doesn't work as one would expect.

Comment: You are right. (Seems that I've made some kind of mistake when I tested it 2 days ago…) Then this seems to be another mystery about `Unevaluated`.