# When must I use the Return function?

Tags: evaluation, core-language

In a comment to my answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58014/3066), QuantumDot asks, "Where can I find more information on when I must use the 'Return' function?". I found this too deep a question to be answered by leaving a comment in reply. I think it deserves to be asked as an question in own right.

I am posting my answer below, but I hope there will be others. I doubt I have the definitive view of this matter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Return` is surprisingly under-documented, but I would still recommend reading [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Return.html) as a start. `Return` has an undocumented feature which you can read about [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6815/3066)

But none of the above really answers the question. Frankly, I can't come up with a situation that absolutely requires the use of `Return`, although I can think of several where using `Return` is convenient.

That said, I will try to give a rule-of-thumb. Use `Return` to terminate the evaluation of a compound expression inside a function at any point before the final argument of the compound expression is evaluated. Does that read as gibberish? To make sense of it, recall that `a; b; c` is actually the short form of `CompoundExpression[a, b, c]`, which returns whatever `c` evaluates to. To get `a; b; c` to stop after evaluating `b` and return, write `a; Return[b]; c` instead.

Of course, in normal usage `Return` will be placed in some kind of conditional construct. For example,

```
f[x_] := (a; If[x > 0, Return[a]]; b)
{f[42], f[-42]}
```

> ```
> {a, b}
> ```

But this can be rewritten, as all the cases I can think of, to eliminate the use of `Return`.

```
g[x_] := If[x > 0, a, b]
```

So when is it practical to use `Return` in "real" code? I find myself using `Return` in the definitions of functions that have non-standard evaluation; e.g., functions that have the the `HoldAll` attribute. In such functions, there is a need to validate arguments that have been passed in. It is convenient to do this up front, using `Return` to cut short evaluation should a bad argument be found. Here is a rather contrived example.

```
Clear @ h
SetAttributes[h, HoldAll];
h::badarg = "`1` = `2` is not valid";
h[x_, y_] :=
  Module[{result = $default},
If[! MatchQ[x, _Integer /; x > 0], Message[h::badarg, "x", x]; Return[$Failed]];
    If[! MatchQ[y, _Real], Message[h::badarg, "y", y ]; Return[$Failed]];
    (* do some long computation here *)
    result]

h[42, 42.]
```

> ```
> $default
> ```

```
h[-42, 42.]
```

> h::badarg: x = -42 is not valid
>
> ```
>  $Failed
> ```

```
h[42, 42]
```

> h::badarg: y = 42 is not valid
>
> ```
>  $Failed
> ```

Another thing good to know about `Return` is that it is not a function in the ordinary *Mathematica* sense. It's a symbol which has special meaning to the *Mathematica* evaluator and which causes a side effect. If `Return` were an ordinary function `a; Return[b]; c` would be the same as `a; b; c`.

The non-functional behavior of `Return` is demonstrated by the following rather peculiar sequence of evaluations.

```
expr = CompoundExpression[a, Return[b], c];
```

> ```
> Return[b]
> ```

```
OwnValues @ expr
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[expr] :> Return[b]}
> ```

```
expr
```

> ```
> b
> ```

Answer (score 14):

I think the most direct answer to this question is: **rarely.**

#### Incorrect Usage

A great majority of the appearances of [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Return.html) that I see are either entirely superfluous or an indication of code in need of refactoring.  For example I frequently see something like:

```
fn[x_] :=
  Module[{vec},
    vec = {1, 2, 3};
    Do[vec[[i]] *= x, {i, 1, Length[vec]}];
    Return[vec]
  ]
```

`Return` is superfluous here as omitting it will produce the same result.  And of course the rest this code would be written *far* more simply which is often true in such cases.

#### Correct Usage

`Return` does have its place, as does its sister function [`Break`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Break.html).  These functions are the most direct way to exit an ongoing incremental evaluation, and optionally return a value.  It is important to understand how they work but there are already questions on that subject:

- [How does Return work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29353/121)
- [What can I use as the second argument to Return in my own functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6815/121)

Although mostly undocumented I often, even typically, use these functions with additional parameters:

- [Is there a Break[] equivalent for short-circuiting in Table?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18519/121)

This not only extends the application of `Return` and `Break` but it more clearly defines the behavior of the operation which may make it more robust through [version changes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931716/how-to-test-if-a-list-contains-consecutive-integers-in-mathematica/7934354#comment9697571_7934354)

One must understand the order of evaluation and operation of *Mathematica* functions to effectively use `Return` and `Break`.  For example it is not possible to `Break[]` out of a `Map` operation because `Map` *first* applies the function, *then* evaluates the expression, as explained here:

- [Scan vs. Map vs. Apply](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46238/121)

However `Scan` does use an incremental evaluation which means that we can `Return` or `Break` from it:

```
Scan[
  If[# > 2, Return[#]] &,
  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

Critically, though not illustrated, the `Function` is never applied to elements `4` and `5`.

The question title is not when *should* I use `Return` but rather when *must* I use return and that is even more rare, if ever.  The operation above can also be written using [`Throw`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Throw.html) and [`Catch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Catch.html):

```
Scan[
  If[# > 2, Throw[#]] &,
  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
] // Catch
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

(Like `Return` using the second parameter of `Throw` and `Catch` will make this operation more robust.)

#### Exclusive Usage

I am not prepared to say that there is ever a case where one *must* use `Return` as there are so often clever alternative methods in *Mathematica*.  However one example where it is at least *far easier* to use `Return` is if it is not practical to insert a `Catch` at an arbitrary place in the evaluation.

Suppose we have a function with multiple internal operations which itself accepts a function:

```
func[f_, dat_] := Array[f, #, #2] & ~MapIndexed~ dat ~Flatten~ {2}

func[f, {4, 1, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{f[1], f[2], f[3]}, {f[2], f[4]}, {f[3], f[5]}, {f[4]}}
> ```

Without modifying `func` we can use `Return` to affect the evaluation in different ways:

```
func[If[# > 4, Return[{0, 7, 9}, Array], #] &, {4, 1, 3}]

func[If[# > 4, Return[{{1, 2}, {3}}, MapIndexed], #] &, {4, 1, 3}]

func[If[# > 4, Return["foo", func], #] &, {4, 1, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 0}, {2, 7}, {3, 9}, {4}}
>
> {{1, 3}, {2}}
>
> "foo"
> ```

I apologize for obfuscation from what was perhaps a poorly chosen example function, but the point is that we can exit from and return a value for an individual use of `Array`, or the one call to `MapIndexed`, or the entire function `func`.

Note that there was no example of `Flatten` for the parameter of `Return` because it does not work:

```
func[If[# > 4, Return["x", Flatten], #] &, {4, 1, 3}]
```

> Return::nofunc: Function Flatten not found enclosing Return[x,Flatten]. >>
>
> ```
> Hold[Return["x", Flatten]]
> ```

The reason for this is complicated and it is the subject of Rojo's answer found in the second bulleted link from the top of this post.

Comment: I gave a link to Rojo's answer in my answer as auxiliary reading. It's a great contribution and definitely related to this question, but in my opinion, not quite on-topic for the issue under consideration here.

Comment: @m_goldberg That's why I also included a link, but only a link, in my answer.  Although I hope that my answer is complementary to yours I also wanted to make it stand on its own so I thought it important to reference some guides to the rather mysterious behavior of `Return`.

Comment: I feel your answer is entirely complementary to mine, and is exactly the kind of additional answer I was hoping would be posted.

Comment: @m_goldberg Okay. :-)

Answer (score 7):

I think I find a situation that *almost* absolutely requires the use of `Return`. Using `Return` seems to be the only *documented* way to exit from a [`Dialog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dialog.html) and return a value:

[image]

Sadly(?) there's a undocumented function `ExitDialog` that can be used for the task, too. (Still, `Return` and `ExitDialog` have subtle difference, read [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18271/1871) for more information.)

Comment: Nice addition.  I cannot think of a time I productively used `Dialog`.  Is this function arcane or do other people find regular use for it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think it's not arcane and have a feeling that it's underestimated, but I admit I almost never used this function, too…