# Procedural implementation of factorial

Tags: functions, function-construction

I'm a Mathematica beginner.

I want to define a factorial function in a procedural way. There are other ways to define factorial function, but I'm asking about the Mathematica grammar equivalent to a for-loop in C++.

Here is the code in C++. How would I convert the code to Mathematica code?

```cpp
int fac(int n)
{
    int res = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        res *= i;
    }
    return res;
}
```

How do I convert `res *= i;` and `return res;` to Mathematica equivalent?

Comment: It is not recommended to use procedural loops in Mathematica. If you insist,  `TimesBy` function has exactly the same syntax as C; and you do not need the `Return` function in this case, simply put the return value at the end of the function without semicolon.

Comment: Take a look at [**2639**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2639/5478) too.

Comment: These links may be useful: [`TimesBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimesBy.html), [When must I use the Return function?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58059/121), [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121).  One solution: `Module[{res = 1}, Do[res *= i, {i, #}]; res] &`.  More idiomatically `Product[i, {i, #}] &`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica has a much sneered at `For` function that exists for the purpose of making it easy to translate C/C++ code like yours into Mathematica form.  For your function, the translation looks like

```
fac[n_Integer /; n > 0] :=
  Module[{res = 1, i},
    For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, res *= i];
    res]
```

and

```
fac[6]
```

> `720`

Be aware, however, there is a lot syntactic sugar in this code. In Mathematica, comma ( , ) is the only delimiter. Semi-colon ( ; ) is neither a delimiter nor a terminator -- it is the binary operator form of the function [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html). `Return` is essentially never needed. Mathematica functions return the value of the last expression they evaluate. `Module` is a form that localizes variables, but not quite in the same way the `{ ... }` does in C++.