# Use of Module With Functions

Tags: scoping

Really confused by how one should use the `Module[]` command in two variables. For example my function here should return the `DigitalRoot` of a number; i.e. `func[5432] -> 14 -> 5` or for `func[23] -> 5`.

My example uses the `Module` command but the solution is wrong;

```
Fox[a_] := Module[
  {x1, x2},
  x1 = 0; 
  x2 = a; 
  While[
    x1 != 1, 
    x1 = Length[IntegerDigits[x2]]; 
    x2 = Total[InterDigits[x2]]; 
    Return[x2]
  ]
]
```

The `Module[]` and `While[]` don't appear to loop, so `Fox[5432] = 5432` and `Fox[23] = 23`.

Maybe my understanding of the `Module[]` command is wrong.

Please help

Answer (score 9):

Your approach works fine, aside from one typo, [`InterDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterDigits.html), and the fact that you have a [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Return.html) inside the `While` statement, when [you rarely need to use](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58059/9490) `Return` at all.

```
Fox[a_] := Module[
    {x1, x2},
    x1 = 0;
    x2 = a;
    While[x1 =!= 1,
        x1 = Length[ IntegerDigits[ x2 ] ];
        x2 = Total[ IntegerDigits[ x2 ] ];
    ];
    (* no need to use Return, just return the value *)
    x2
]
```

Answer (score 6):

better way..

```
Fox[a_] :=
 NestWhile[Total@IntegerDigits@# & , a , 
  Length@IntegerDigits@# != 1 & ]
```

or

```
Fox[a_] :=
  NestWhile[Total@IntegerDigits@# & , a , # > 10 & ]
```

Comment: I like the functional style! You could use the infix composition `@*` to make it [pointfree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming), e.g. `Total@*IntegerDigits` or even `(IntegerDigits/*Length/*(Not@*EqualTo[1]))` :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what your scoping is attempting to accomplish. If your question needs to be solved with a scoping construct, I'm not sure where to go, but you might want to try

```
singDigitNumberSum[num_] := If[
    Length[IntegerDigits[num]] === 1, 
    num, 
    singDigitNumberSum[Total[IntegerDigits[num]]]
]
```

with an appropriate `$RecursionLimit`.