# Assume symbolic elements as reals in TensorExpand

Tags: expression-manipulation

Let's assume that a, b are complex variables, and A[t],B[u], C[t,u] are matrices.

```
In[1]   TensorExpand[(a A[t].B[u] + b C[t, u]).C[t, u]]
Out[1]  (b C[t, u]).C[t, u] + (a A[t].B[u]).C[t, u]
```

Now this is not quite what I want. Since a and b are complex, the parentheses are unnecessary. But wait, I can let Mathematica know, that they are not vectors or matrices:

```
In[1]  $Assumptions = Element[{a, b}, Complexes]
       TensorExpand[(a A[t].B[u] + b C[t, u]).C[t, u]]
Out[1] b C[t, u].C[t, u] + a A[t].B[u].C[t, u]
```

But I want to take this one step further, let's write a function that takes care of the job:

```
In[1]  myExpand[expr_] := Module[{},
           $Assumptions = Element[_Symbol, Complexes];
           Return[TensorExpand[expr]];
       ]
Out[1] (b C[t, u]).C[t, u] + (a A[t].B[u]).C[t, u]
```

Well, that didn't work as I wanted. But I can still read all the symbolic variables:

```
In[1]  symbolicQ[x_] := MatchQ[Head[x], Symbol];
       myExpand[expr_] := Module[{},
           $Assumptions = Element[DeleteDuplicates[Select[Level[expr, Infinity], symbolicQ]], Complexes];
           Return[TensorExpand[expr]];
       ]
```

However, this feels clumsy. <strike>Is there a better way?</strike> What is the better way? If in doubt, choose the more performant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
myExpand[expr_] := Assuming[
  Cases[expr, _Symbol, All] ∈ Reals,
  TensorExpand@expr
  ]

myExpand[(a A[t].B[u] + b C[t, u]).C[t, u]]
(* b C[t, u].C[t, u] + a A[t].B[u].C[t, u] *)
```

A few notes:

- Your `Module` is unnecessary - it doesn't do anything like this
- `Return` is also unnecessary (even with `Module`). See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58059/when-must-i-use-the-return-function)
- If you want to temporarily set `$Assumptions`, use [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html). In general (i.e. when there's no function that does it for you, use [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html): `Block[{$var=…},…]`
- Use `Cases[expr,pat,level]` instead of `Select[Level[expr,level],check]`
- Use `MatchQ[expr,_head]` instead of `MatchQ[Head[expr],head]`. This also makes using `Cases` more natural in this case

Comment: Thank you quite a lot, also for your additional remarks. They are really helpful in my journey of learning mathematica :)