# Assume Symbolic Elements as Scalars in Distribute

Tags: expression-manipulation

So yesterday I asked about [TensorExpand](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175687/assume-symbolic-elements-as-reals-in-tensorexpand) but it turns out that it is way too slow for my needs. I want Mathematica to know that my symbolic variables are scalars, so I don't have the parentheses in my result.

[Lukas Lang came up with this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175690/27951) for `TensorExpand`:

```
myExpand[expr_] := 
  Assuming[Cases[expr, _Symbol, All] \[Element] Reals, 
   Simplify[TensorExpand@expr]];

myExpand[(k*f[a] + f[b]).(f[a, b] + g[a, b])]
(* Out: k f[a].f[a, b] + k f[a].g[a, b] + f[b].f[a, b] + f[b].g[a, b] *)
```

How can I achieve the same with `Distribute`? I obviously tried replacing `TensorExpand` with `Distribute` but that didn't work.

**Update**

In the end, I want a list of the form

```
{{{k}, {f[a], f[a, b]}}, 
 {{k}, {f[a], g[a, b]}}, 
 {{},  {f[b], f[a, b]}}, 
 {{},  {f[b], g[a, b]}}}
```

I have a working approach, but that does not work when there are parentheses in the expanded expression.

Comment: "so I don't have the parentheses in my result": why does it matter? Does it influence anything downstream?

Comment: I've updated the OP. It influences my further manipulation. If there is a quick way to get to my desired result, I'll take it as well :)

Comment: I wonder if we are falling into the dreaded "XY problem" situation here ([What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)), i.e. you are trying to fix the steps in your *solution*, rather than trying to solve your *actual problem*. Perhaps you could improve your question to include the end goal, together with the complete path you have so far. Once we know the context of the problem, a simpler, different solution might present itself.

Comment: I'd like to link this question to its extension from the same author ([Split expression into nested list of summands, times and dot products](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175783/split-expression-into-nested-list-of-summands-times-and-dot-products)).