# Split expression into nested list of summands, times and dot products

Tags: expression-manipulation

In order to avoid the XY Problem we might have encountered in [another question I asked](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175770/assume-symbolic-elements-as-scalars-in-distribute), here I ask a new question with full context:

I want to get a list representation of an expanded expression, such that the outer level resembles the summands and in the next level I have two list consisting of all elements that are ordinarily multiplicated and the elements that are matrix multiplicated.

Expression:

```
(k*f[a] + f[b]).(f[a, b] + g[a, b])
```

Desired Output:

```
{{{k}, {f[a], f[a, b]}}, 
 {{k}, {f[a], g[a, b]}}, 
 {{},  {f[b], f[a, b]}}, 
 {{},  {f[b], g[a, b]}}}
```

I have a working solution with Tensor Expand, but that is way too slow, if the expression gets too big.

Also, I did not intend to post it here, so be warned, it is cumbersome.

```
Clear[doProducts];
doProducts[list_] := {Times @@ list[[1]], Dot @@ # & /@ list[[2]]}
Clear[createProducts];
createProduct[list_] := list[[1]]*list[[2]]
Clear[splitTimes];
splitTimes[arg_] := Module[{expr = arg},
    If[MatchQ[expr, HoldPattern[Times[_, __]]], expr = Level[expr, 1],
     expr = {expr}];
    Return[expr];
   ];
Clear[splitTimesDot];
splitTimesDot[arg_] := Module[{expr = arg, pos},
    pos = Flatten@Position[expr, Dot[_, __]];
    If[Length[pos] == 0, pos = 1, pos = pos[[1]]];
    (*Print["pos:",pos]*);
    splitList[arg, pos]
   ];
Clear[splitDot];
splitDot[arg_] := Module[{expr = arg},
    If[MatchQ[expr, HoldPattern[Dot[_, __]]], expr = Level[expr, 1], 
    expr = {expr}];
    Return[expr];
   ];
Clear[splitList];
splitList[list_List, position_Integer] := {Take[list, position - 1], 
   Take[list, position - 1 - Length[list]]};
Clear[myExpand];
myExpand[expr_] := 
  Assuming[Cases[expr, _Symbol, All] \[Element] Reals, 
   TensorExpand@expr];
Clear[mapSecond];
mapSecond[function_, list_List] := {list[[1]], 
   Map[function, list[[2]]]};
Clear[prepareExpression];
prepareExpression[arg_] := Module[{expr = myExpand[arg], list, pos},
    Print["prepareExpressionStart"];
    list = {expr};
    If[MatchQ[expr, HoldPattern[Plus[_, __]]], 
    list = Level[expr, 1]];
    (*Print["list1", list]*);
    list = splitTimes[#] & /@ list;
    (*Print["list2",list]*);
    list = splitTimesDot[#] & /@ list;
    (*Print["list3",list]*);
    Return[mapSecond[splitDot, #] & /@ list];
   ];
milliSeconds := 
  ToExpression[ToString[UnixTime[]] <> DateString["Millisecond"]];
```

If I now call

```
prepareExpression[(k*f[a] + f[b]).(f[a, b] + g[a, b])]
```

I get the desired result:

```
{{{k}, {{f[a], f[a, b]}}}, {{k}, {{f[a], g[a, b]}}}, {{}, {{f[b], 
f[a, b]}}}, {{}, {{f[b], g[a, b]}}}}
```

Question (as mentioned above):
How can I speed this up, with `TensorExpand` being so terribly slow and `Distribute` disrupting my `Level`?

**More complicated test case**

```
expr = (3/c*f[a] + f[b]).(g[a, b] - 3*h[a, b]*c)
desiredResult = prepareExpression[(3/c*f[a] + f[b]).(g[a, b] - 3*h[a, b]*c)]
{{{3, 1/c}, {{f[a], g[a, b]}}}, {{-9}, {{f[a], 
h[a, b]}}}, {{}, {{f[b], g[a, b]}}}, {{-3, c}, {{f[b], h[a, b]}}}}
```

**Test Case 3**

```
testCase3 = (k*{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}.f[a] + 
 f[b].g[a, b]).(3*(-{{3, 3}, {2, 2}}).f[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, b]);
prepareExpression[testCase3]
{{{3}, {{f[b], g[a, b], {{-3, -3}, {-2, -2}}, 
f[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, b]}}}, {{3, 
k}, {{{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, f[a], {{-3, -3}, {-2, -2}}, 
f[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, b]}
```

**Testcase where TensorCalc is too slow**

This already takes over a minute just to apply regular TensorCalc

```
TensorExpand[(k*f[a].g[b] + f[b].g[a]).(f[c].g[d] - 
     3*f[d].g[c]).(f[h].g[i] + f[i].g[h]).(f[j].g[k] + 
     f[k].g[j]).(f[l].g[m] + f[m].g[l]).(f[p].g[q] + 
     f[o].g[n]).(f[n].g[o] + f[o].g[n]).(f[n].g[o] + 
     f[o].g[n]).(f[p].g[q] - 
     3 k*f[q].g[p]).(f[r].g[s].+f[s].g[r]).(f[t].g[u] + 
     f[u].g[t]*3)] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: Does something like `Distribute[expr] /. {Plus -> List, 
  Dot[Times[k_: Nothing, f_[x__]], g_[y__]] :> {{k}, {f[x], g[y]}}}` work?  Or is that not general enough?

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunatly that fails on another test case, that I just added to the OP. Can you elaborate, what `k_: Nothing` means?

Comment: What's an example of an input where `TensorExpand` is too slow?

Comment: I've added another one. Distribute Solves that one in a fraction of a second while TensorExpand takes 65s.

Comment: @CarlWoll By the way, the reason `TensorExpand` is so slow is revealed by looking at its source code with ``Get["GeneralUtilities`"]; PrintDefinitions[TensorExpand]``. One can tell that it was written by Major Noob since there's the line `Expand[Expand[expr //. $TensorExpandRules] //. $TensorExpandRules]`, where `$TensorExpandRules` is a list of 118 rules.  This is another example of a built-in function one should stay away from like the plague.