# Formatting InputForm output

Tags: output-formatting, input-forms

I have a function that operates on EventData and has a return value that has Properties (or things that act like Properties).  I'd like to clean up the return InputForm when queried, but I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

```
myfunc[x_] := Module[{returnvalue},
  returnvalue["Data"] = x;
  returnvalue["Mean"] = Mean[x];
  Format[returnvalue, StandardForm] := HoldForm["myfunc"][x];
  Format[returnvalue, InputForm] := HoldForm["myfunc"][x];
  Return[returnvalue]
]
```

My data is just EventData:

```
e = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
ci = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
dat = EventData[e, ci];

a = myfunc[dat]
```

When I run `InputForm[a]`, I get the following:

```
HoldForm["myfunc"][EventData[Automatic, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, None}]]
```

What I'd like to get is:

```
myfunc[EventData[Automatic, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, None}]]
```

How should I define the `Format` command in the body of `myfunc` to get the output that I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`SequenceForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceForm) instead of [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm) (and [don't](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58089/45431) use [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Return)):

```
myfunc[x_] := Module[{returnvalue},
    returnvalue["Data"] = x;
    returnvalue["Mean"] = Mean[x];
    Format[returnvalue, StandardForm] := HoldForm["myfunc"][x];
    Format[returnvalue, InputForm] := SequenceForm[myfunc][x];
    returnvalue
]
```

Your example:

```
e = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
ci = {0,1,0,0,0,1};
dat = EventData[e,ci];

a = myfunc[dat];
a //InputForm
```

> myfunc[EventData[Automatic, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, None}]]

Comment: SequenceForm is listed as an obsolete symbol now, but the replacements, Row and Text didn't seem to work the same way.