# Variable order in Solve

Tags: equation-solving

I suspect this is a bug.  Further, I suspect it is already known, but I have not seen another example.

```
Solve[{0.7 == ha + a, 1.88 == 3.86 + Log10[a/ha]}, {a, ha}]
(* {{a -> 0.00725394, ha -> 0.692746}} *)
Solve[{0.7 == ha + a, 1.88 == 3.86 + Log10[a/ha]}, {ha, a}]
(* {} *)
```

Apparently, my students are correct, and buffer calculations are hard.

It seems to be a problem with whatever *non-equivalent transformations* means since adding either of the options `Method->Reduce` or `VerifySolutions->True` appears to resolve the variable-order-dependent solution.

The **question**: Is this behavior a bug or working as intended?

Tested on WIN 12.0.0 and RPI 12.0.1

Comment: Related? [(17926)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17926/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was wondering if this was the quirky variable naming but but with the limited number of variable names I tried, I could not see a pattern.

Answer (score 4):

```
eqns = {0.7 == ha + a, 1.88 == 3.86 + Log10[a/ha]};
```

Use exact values

```
sol1 = Solve[eqns // Rationalize, {a, ha}] // Simplify

(* {{a -> 7/(10 + 100 10^(49/50)), ha -> 70/(100 + 10^(1/50))}} *)

sol1 // N

(* {{a -> 0.00725394, ha -> 0.692746}} *)

sol2 = Solve[eqns // Rationalize, {ha, a}] // Simplify

(* {{ha -> 70/(100 + 10^(1/50)), a -> 7/(10 + 100 10^(49/50))}} *)

sol2 // N

(* {{ha -> 0.692746, a -> 0.00725394}} *)
```

Comment: Certainly a workaround.  I'm still wondering, though, why the order of variables is in any way related to whether or not exact values are used.

Answer (score 2):

In MMA Version 8.0 not `Rationalize` but `Simplify` of equations is sufficient to get right results both times.

```
Solve[{0.7 == ha + a, 1.88 == 3.86 + Log10[a/ha]} // Simplify, {a, ha}]

Solve[{0.7 == ha + a, 1.88 == 3.86 + Log10[a/ha]} // Simplify, {ha, a}]
```

Comment: Generally, though, one should give `Solve` exact input. It sometimes fails to cope with approximate numbers.

Comment: @JohnDoty While in practice this appears to be true, I see no explicit statement in the documentation stating one should give the function exact input.  Have I missed something?

Comment: @bobthechemist The documentation doesn't always cover best practice. For `Return` it should say "Be sure you understand what this does before using it. Once you understand, you'll be hard pressed to find a sensible use case."

Comment: @JohnDoty `Return` has its place [in my opinion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58089/121).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I didn't say it was impossible to find a sensible use case. Your example proves my point: the case you came up with was pretty obscure.