# Function Parameter Substitution Problem

Tags: function-construction

I have this function

```
BSprice[S_, K_, r_, T_, v_, PutCall_] :=
  Module[{d, bscall},
   bscall = 0.0;
   d = (Log[S/K] + T*(r + 0.5*v^2))/(v*Sqrt[T]);
   bscall = S*Gauss[d] - Exp[-r*T]*K*Gauss[d - v*Sqrt[T]];
   If[PutCall == "Call",
    Return[bscall],
    Return[bscall - S + K*Exp[-r*T]];
    ];
   ];
```

and when I explicitly put in the parameter values, I get

```
BSprice[319.0, 355, 0.02, 35/365, 0.1584, "Call"]
```

```
0.0952009
```

But when I try to do substitutions, it's another story...I get

```
BSprice[x, k1, r, T, \[Sigma]1, "Call"] /. {x -> 319.0, k1 -> 355, 
  r -> 0.02, T -> 35/365, \[Sigma]1 -> 0.1584}
```

```
-35.3198 Null
```

Why does this happen? What am I doing wrong? Thanks for assistance...

The other functions needed are:

```
Gauss[x_] := NormSDist[x];
```

```
NormSDist[x_] :=
  Module[{t, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, p, c},
   t = 0;
   b1 = 0.31938153;
   b2 = -0.356563782;
   b3 = 1.781477937;
   b4 = -1.821255978;
   b5 = 1.330274429;
   p = 0.2316419;
   c = 0.39894228;
   If[x >= 0,
    t = 1.0/(1.0 + p*x);
    Return[(1.0 - 
       c*Exp[-x*x/2.0]*t*(t*(t*(t*(t*b5 + b4) + b3) + b2) + b1))],
    t = 1.0/(1.0 - p*x);
    Return[(c*Exp[-x*x/2.0]*
       t*(t*(t*(t*(t*b5 + b4) + b3) + b2) + b1))]];
   ];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**What is the problem?** If you run

```
NormSDist[undefinedsymbol]
```

you will get no return value, meaning `Null`. The problem is that your `If[x >= 0,...]` cannot decide if `x >= 0` is true or not, and therefore will not evaluate either of your `Return`.

Please see the [`If`-documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html?q=If):

> If[condition,t,f] is left unevaluated if condition evaluates to neither True nor False.

**Solution.** Rewrite your function `NormSDist` without `Return`. Also remove the semicolon after `If` and only rely on the fact that the last expression in your `Module` is returned:

```
NormSDist[x_]:=Module[{t,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,p,c},t=0;
  b1=0.31938153;
  b2=-0.356563782;
  b3=1.781477937;
  b4=-1.821255978;
  b5=1.330274429;
  p=0.2316419;
  c=0.39894228;
  If[x>=0,
    t=1.0/(1.0+p*x);
    (1.0-c*Exp[-x*x/2.0]*t*(t*(t*(t*(t*b5+b4)+b3)+b2)+b1)), (* no Return *)
    t=1.0/(1.0-p*x);
    (c*Exp[-x*x/2.0]*t*(t*(t*(t*(t*b5+b4)+b3)+b2)+b1)) (* no Return *)
    ] (* no semicolon *)
];
```

Now

```
BSprice[x,k1,r,T,\[Sigma]1,"Call"]/. {x->319.0,k1->355,r->0.02,T->35/365,\[Sigma]1->0.1584}
```

also gives `0.0952009`.

**Comment.** I never use the `Return` function. Various reasons for why one should not use `Return` are given in [this old newsgroup thread](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/c/EkGXJ8CWyq0). See also [this Mathematica SE post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58059).

**Comment.** While the above works, I would probably write this function as follows:

```
NormSDist[x_]:=With[{
  b1=0.31938153,
  b2=-0.356563782,
  b3=1.781477937,
  b4=-1.821255978,
  b5=1.330274429,
  p=0.2316419,
  c=0.39894228},
  With[{aux=Function[{t},c*Exp[-x*x/2.0]*t*(t*(t*(t*(t*b5+b4)+b3)+b2)+b1)]},
    If[x>=0,1.0-aux[1.0/(1.0+p*x)],aux[1.0/(1.0-p*x)]]]];
```

**Note.** There is actually a much simpler solution to your problem, namely you could change your original definition and add `NumericQ` as in

```
NormSDist[x_?NumericQ]:=...
```

The `NumericQ` prevents evaluation as long as the argument is not numeric. But I hope the answer above is more useful.