# Aborting from a Dialog box

Tags: functions, evaluation, dialog-window

I'm trying to abort a `While` cycle, with a dialog box. I've tried the following:

```
res = 0;
res2 = "";
CreateDialog[{TextCell["Do you want to continue calculations?"], 
              Button["Proceed", DialogReturn[res2 = True]], 
              Button["Cancel", DialogReturn[res2 = Abort[]]]}];

While[True , res++; If[res > 10, res = -1]; res2];
```

However, this does not work. It's important that the `Dialog` window may be left opened while the `While` continues to 'work'.

I've tried [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18270/aborting-from-inside-a-dialog) but I was unable to adapt that solution to my problem...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I see you have not accepted any of your questions' anwsers. Aren't they useful? Please take a [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how it works.

Comment: @Kuba thanks and sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `SetDelayed` then you loop will call `Abort`. With `Set` (`=`) `res2` has not value at all. You can check it evaluating:

```
a =. ;
a = Abort[]

(*new cell*)

a
```

> ```
> a
> ```

So:

```
res = 0;
res2 = "";

CreateDialog[{TextCell["Do you want to continue calculations?"], 
              Button["Proceed", DialogReturn[res2 = True]], 
              Button["Cancel", DialogReturn[res2 := Abort[]]]}];

While[True, res++; If[res > 10, res = -1]; res2];
```

will do what you need.