# How to abort evaluation when clicking CancelButton

Tags: front-end, dynamic

If you run the following code you will notice that the evaluation continues in the following cells.

I want to abort evolution if `CancelButton` is clicked.

I tried to use `FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluatorAbort"]` but it doesn't help:

```
DynamicModule[{yyyy = 2015, mm = 6, dd = 20}, DialogInput[Grid[{
     {"Year:", InputField[Dynamic[yyyy], Number]},
     {"Month:", InputField[Dynamic[mm], Number]},
     {"Day:", InputField[Dynamic[dd], Number]},
     {CancelButton[
       DialogReturn[FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluatorAbort"]]], 
      DefaultButton[DialogReturn[{Year = yyyy, Month = mm, Day = dd}]]}
     }, Spacings -> {1, Automatic}, Alignment -> Left]]];

RandomReal[]
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: related: [stop notebook evaluation when Assert fails](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98882/5478) and [Aborting from a Dialog box](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69014/5478)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far and with help of Kuba's links I got the following solution:

```
DynamicModule[{yyyy = 2015, mm = 6, dd = 20, cancel = False}, 
  DialogInput[Grid[{
     {"Year:", InputField[Dynamic[yyyy], Number]},
     {"Month:", InputField[Dynamic[mm], Number]},
     {"Day:", InputField[Dynamic[dd], Number]},
     {CancelButton[DialogReturn[cancel = True]], 
      DefaultButton[
       DialogReturn[{Year = yyyy, Month = mm, Day = dd}]]}}, 
    Spacings -> {1, Automatic}, Alignment -> Left]];
  If[cancel, FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluatorAbort"]]];
```

Comment: It doesn't work on my machine (Mathematica 10.0.2.0,Windows 7).  That is to say : `RandomReal[]`is still evaluated when I push the button "Cancel". (I must leave. Be back in 11 hours)

Comment: @andre you probably mean that you have `RandomReal[]` in the same cell that `DynamicModule` is. Then that's correct.

Comment: @andre and if you want to abort what is scheduled in current cell I'm afraid you have to use my stupid `$AssertFunction` from linked thread.

Comment: @Kuba You are certainly right. I can reproduce what you say. Nevertheless.  I thought that `RandomReal[]` was in a separate cell this morning. I have done a mistake somewhere else probably, but i can't reproduce it.